# Using a Javascript object in an if statement

Tags: javascript, function, object

Hi I'm fairly new to Javascript code and can't seem to get some code to work, any help would be really appreciated

I'm trying to pass an object property into an if statement using a function argument as follows:

```
function newmodalcontrols(modalspec) {
    if (modelContentCall[modalspec].description == true) {
        $(this).load('Content_for_injection.htm #description');
        alert('description true2');
        }
```

Where the object literal is `modalContentCall` with nested properties. The format to call what I want is:

`modelContentCall.dynamicvariable.description` but I need `dynamicvariable` to be dynamic.

My event handler looks like this for the object property of add_expense_se:

```
$('.add_expense_link').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('href')=="#add_expense_se") {
    $(this).parent().next().find('.tailoredins').newmodalcontrols(add_expense_se);
    }
```

I have defined the object and all my code within a document ready function.

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: Your question has answer ....!!!

Comment: When I run the above code the alert does not show, I can't figure out why. Does my code look ok?

Comment: The main problem is that you appear to be trying to call `newmodalcontrols` as a jQuery function when it is just a normal javascript function. Where does the `add_expense_se` variable come from?

Comment: `modelContentCall[modalspec].description` part looks fine. I would suggest you to debug your js code via chrome developer console or firebug to see your object's real content. It may not realy have the dynamic property you are passing. Also the dynamic property `modalspec` may be null at all.

Comment: add an else in newmodalcontrols and verify that function is called..  you should add newmodalcontrols as prototype before using like this

Comment: That's a param I'm passing to the function to select an object property of the same name and return boolean data which will trigger the load function above if true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in trying to call the function as a jQuery function where it had been created as a JavaScript function. I changed the code in line 1 from:

```
function newmodalcontrols(modalspec) {
```

to

```
$.fn.newmodalcontrols = function(modalspec) {
```

This allowed the function to be called as normal in jQuery and the code now works.